# Streams, check that two lists of objects has same nested lists of another objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have List of log events that I shoud check, that they are the same as should be.
There is structure of Event object:

```
public class Event {
    public String type;
    public List<Item> items;

    public Event(String type, List<Item> items) {
        this.type = type;
        this.items = items;
    }
}
public class Item {
    public String id;
    public String value;

    public Item(String id, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Lets fill "should" object, "real" object and check that they have same items

```
List<Event> should = asList(
                new Event("1000", asList(new Item("server_id", "1"), new Item("user_id", "11"))),
                new Event("1000", asList(new Item("server_id", "1"), new Item("user_id", "11"))));
        List<Event> logged = asList(
                new Event("1000", asList(new Item("server_id", "1"), new Item("user_id", "11"))),
                new Event("1000", asList(new Item("server_id", "1"), new Item("user_id", "11"))));
        boolean logMatch = logged.stream()
                                    .allMatch(e1 ->
                                            should.stream()
                                                      .allMatch(e2 -> e2.items
                                                                        .stream()
                                                                        .allMatch(a2 -> e1.items
                                                                                          .stream()
                                                                                          .anyMatch(a1 -> a1.value.equals(a2.value)))));
        System.out.println(logMatch);
```

It's true, but I have an issue, if I change any value of "should" to "11", I'll get true. How can I fix this or how to make this comparison simpler?

Comment: Are you checking that all `value` fields are equal on an item-to-item basis?

Comment: @ernest_k i want to check that every Event from one list has same in another list. Events will be same if there id/value of all items will be the same. And i totally broke my brain when i tried to write this:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're just checking that each `logged` element has at least an element in the `should` list with which it has the same `value`. You rather want to check that the two `value` collections are equivalent.

A simple correction can use list comparison in this case:

```
List<String> actualValues =  logged.stream().flatMap(l -> l.items.stream())
        .map(i -> i.value).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> shouldValues = should.stream().flatMap(l -> l.items.stream())
        .map(i -> i.value).collect(Collectors.toList());

boolean logMatch = actualValues.equals(shouldValues);
```

This comparison is strict and takes order into account. If you'd rather ignore the order of elements, you can collect to set to ignore the order of items.

---

EDIT: You can compare actual events if you need to check multiple fields. The following uses a predicate:

```
List<Item> actualValues =  logged.stream().flatMap(l -> l.items.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Item> shouldValues = should.stream().flatMap(l -> l.items.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

BiPredicate<Item, Item> predicate = (item1, item2) -> item1.id.equals(item2.id) 
        && item1.value.equals(item2.value);

boolean res = actualValues.size() == shouldValues.size() //should be same length
        && IntStream.range(0, actualValues.size())
        .filter(i -> !predicate.test(actualValues.get(i), shouldValues.get(i)))
        .count() == 0; //all elements's ID and value must match
```

Comment: Thnx! what about if I want to check both id and value? Check pls UPD of question, i posted

Comment: nice :) but you've made mistake here -> !predicate.test(actualValues.get(i), actualValues.get(i))

Comment: hi! Can you give me an advice? What if i want to check Events in any order? I found that same event can be pushed to logger with delay :)

Comment: @callmedope I mentioned that in the original post. Just change to `....collect(Collectors.toSet());` and redeclare those variables as `Set<String>`. Sets would not take order into account.

Comment: thnx, i will try :)

Comment: wait, but if i want to compare 2 values, i cant collect them to Set<String>

Comment: @callmedope can you elaborate?

Comment: @ernetst_k https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53536678/how-to-compare-list-of-objects-with-nested-lists :)